# Failed to Configure CA Certificate chain after Rebuilding/Re-Installing OS

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

I got my free ssl at `startssl.com` and it works really fine. My site is working with `https://`. After I configure `LAMP` and `VSFTP` and broke something in there, I decided to re-install UBUNTU 12.04 OS to wipe out all the configurations and unnecessary thing i made in there.

Following the same procedure as I was configuring it before and added the same

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt                           
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key                        
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
```

When I restart the `apache2` it showed `FAILED` instead of `OK`. I immediately run this command `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` and found out the error `Failed to configure CA certificate chain!`.

I followed this post [Failed to configure CA certificate chain](https://serverfault.com/questions/228485/failed-to-configure-ca-certificate-chain) but still no luck.

BTW, I configured my VPS like this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps and it works so fine before i re-install my OS.

Comment: Have you already manually verified the chain of trust of your `ssl.crt` using `openssl verify`? You might be missing an intermediate certificate.

Comment: no, how can i do it? @dawud

Comment: It is quite simple, read the [`verify(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/verify) manpage.

Comment: okay sir. i will try it.